# Draw density plot in R with only mean and sd information

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I wonder to know if we can represent in R (ggplot) a density plot when we only have mean (i.e. 34) and standard deviation (i.e. 4.5).

Comment: `curve(dnorm(x, 34, 4.5), from = 1, to = 60)` is base R, `ggplot() + stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 34, sd = 4.5)) + xlim(1, 60)` is ggplot2

Comment: @qdread [That should be an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment),

Comment: It should be noted that you can plot one distribution with the given mean and standard deviation, but that there are infinite distributions that meet those conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `stat_function` and `dnorm`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  stat_function(fun = ~ dnorm(.x, 34, 4.5), geom = "area",
                fill = "deepskyblue4", alpha = 0.5, color = "black") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  xlim(c(20, 48))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rnorm` to create a sample distribution for a given `mean` and `sd`, then ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = rnorm(10000, mean = 34, sd = 4.5)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
  geom_density(fill = "lightgrey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>